# Can Vows Be Made and Established Mentally

Tags: nedarim-shevuot

Can a vow, i.e “I will” or “I won’t” do something, be said mentally just as it is said verbaly?

Comment: See Yoreh Deah 210

Comment: According to one opinion they even count when said in a dream!